# Graph theory exercise 6

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I've just started learning about graph theory and I am doing some exercises online.

This is the question I'm currently on:

What is the minimum number of edges in a graph with 6 vertices, when there is also a cycle which includes all the vertices of the graph?

---

What is a cycle and what is the best approach to take for working this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cycle of length $n$ (i.e. having $n$ edges) includes exactly $n$ vertices (why?), so if you want all $6$ vertices to be included, you would need a cycle of length $6$, so you need **at least** $6$ edges.

Now is $6$ edges attainable? Consider a hexagon.